# Insert either formula or blank based on the value in other cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am struggling to get this right.

I am trying to either insert a formula in column `B` if column `A` says "AA" or "AB", or leave it as blank if column `A` says "CC".

For example,

if cell `A1` is AA, then the formula needs to be inserted in cell `B1`,

if cell `A2` is AB, then the formula needs to be inserted in cell `B2`,

if cell `A3` is CC, then cell `B3` should be blank.

Does anyone have any idea how I should do this?

Many thanks in advance.

Tim

Comment: This is a easy issue on VBA. What did you try?

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego No I know very little about VBA. Is there a way to do with VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
Sub test()

Dim ws as Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

If ws.Cells(1, 1).Value2 = "AA" Then
    ws.Cells(1, 2).Formula = "Whatever formula you need"
Elseif ws.Cells(2, 1).Value2 = "AB" Then
    ws.Cells(2, 2).Formula = "Whatever formula you need"
Elseif ws.Cells(3, 1).Value2 = "CC" Then
    ws.Cells(3, 2).Formula = "Whatever formula you need"
End If

End Sub
```

That macro will consider your working sheet as "Sheet1", so if it is not your case, please, change it.
On the conditions, as per your explanation, I place the code, just substitute "Whatever formula you need" with the formula you want.
Google how to introduce Excel Formulas on VBA or use VBA functions.

Hope it helps